# Building a nested list with XPath-extracted XML document structure

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to get the text (using xpath) of all `<h2>` tags in:

```
<div id="static_id">
 <div>...
 <a ...>
 <div>...
   <h2>Text 1</h2>
 <a ...>
 <div>...
 <div>...
 <span>...
   <h2>Text 2</h2>
  <a ...>
  <span>...
    <h2>Text 3</h2>

<div id="static_id">
 <div>...
 <span>...
   <h2>Text A</h2>
 <a ...>
 <div>...
 <p>...
 <div>...
   <h2>Text B</h2>
 <a ...>
   <h2>Text C</h2>
 [...]
```

In my HTML source code there are `<div>'s` with the id `static_id`. Within these div's there is just one `<h2>` tag, and I want to get its content. In the end, I would like to have a list that looks like this:

```
lst = [["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"], ["Text A", "Text B", "Text C"]]
```

Please notice that it's a list of lists (every h2-text from one `<div id="static_id">` should end up in a separate list like in the example above.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

I thought I count all `static_id` divs and iterate over all `<h2>` tags to achive this. My approach:

```
list_all = []
div_amount = len(tree.xpath('//div[@id="static_id"]')) # 2 elements in this case (works)
for d in range(1, div_amount+1) # 1,2
  h2_count = len(tree.xpath('//div[@class="static_id"]['+str(d)+']//h2')) #count h2
  lst = []
  for i in range(1, h2_count+1) #1,2,3
    h2_text = ''.join(tree.xpath('//div[@id="static_id"]['+str(d)+']//h2['+i+']/text()'))
    lst.append(h2_text)
  list_all.append(lst)
```

Line 2: Counts all id="static_id"

Line 3: Loop over all id="static_id"

Line 4: Count all h2 (unfortunately all h2's from the HTML source are counted)

Line 5: Loop over all h2's

Line 6: Get h2'text, and next save in list

Can anyone help me out, please? I feel like this could be done easier, but I don't know how.

Comment: Please make your sample data actual, valid XML corresponding with your sample output, such that someone can use it to validate their answer, as opposed to pseudocode that doesn't parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily made a one-liner:

```
list_all = [ static_id_div.xpath('.//h2/text()')
             for static_id_div in tree.xpath('//div[@id="static_id"]') ]
```

The important difference here is that the inner query is being run *against the elements returned by the outer query*, rather than making them work starting from the root of the document.

Comment: omg that is so much better. Thank you so much (one `'` is missing near the end).

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't test because the input wasn't complete, so that got missed. :)